# Hyper-v WSUS timing and reboots

Tags: backup, hyper-v, wsus

I have been playing with Hyper-v and have noticed that having multiple servers and replications are good but can be complicated when WSUS gives you updates that requires reboots.

My environment is 2 HOST and several Hyper-Vs to run our company. Some of our Hyper Vs are replicating so one can go down meanwhile the other is still in action. Some management hosts are "single" however they can be restarted at any time. I have enough space on my SAN so at this point and I have designed a way to update all my servers manually, however I wonder if there is a better way or better practice that people have been performing:

1. Incremental backup and file restore test
2. Export the VM as a restore point (so many people recommended to avoid Checkpoints)
3. perform the updates and reboots
4. check services and applications
5. wait for the next incremental backup and restore file at least
6. delete the export VM

If you have a better and faster solution please share or criticise my method. Any comments are most welcome.

Questions:

- Taking the export **takes a long** time but helps to be able to    restore back at any time after updates. Any better and faster solution?
- having a Hyper-V servers with 2 HOSTs is great however WSUS will apply on all servers any good article to read about how to deal with WSUS on the HOSTs?
- All the restarts required down time in one way or another. Any article on how to minimalise the downtime on services?

I guess some of the questions are broader than a yes or no but I would like to get a better picture on WSUS strategy on a VM system if possible.

Comment: It isn't clear to me at all what you are asking here.  Do you have multiple Hyper-V systems?  Have you set them up in a cluster?  You should be able to move the migrate VMs between nodes pretty easily, if you have shared storage.  There should be no reason for exporting/importing VM things.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I will add my questions in the original post.

Comment: thank you @Ramhound for your time. I simplified my questions and edited the original post as you recommended.

Comment: @Zoredache I have edited the post to give a better description of my system. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: "WSUS will apply on all servers" - You configure the clients to check the for updates by querying the VM running your WSUS